# Reflex to Delete all text except between two lines

Tags: regex, notepad++, multiline

I am trying to extract the content between two lines of string. Here is how the text looks

```
   Hhhshhajsjsjsj
    Hshhejjsjsmk
    Hahjajajajajja
     Message-ID: b123467
       abc
       def
       Kjhshjsjs
     Received:
  Hdjjddjdjdjdjd
```

I need to keep the text between ‘Message-ID’ and ‘Received:’

I tried ‘@“(?:\G(?!\A)[X-Message-ID:)\r?\n(.*)(?>\r?\nReceived:(?=S\r?$))?’

I have got an error ‘can’t find the text’

Comment: Can this text appear multiple times in your file?  What I mean by this is, do you expect to extract _multiple_ texts between multiple message-id/received markers?  Or, is there only a single capture here?

Comment: [`((?<=Message-ID:).*?(?=Received:))|.` replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/esozzP/1)

Comment: What does `keep` mean relative to the entire sample ?

Comment: Hi Tim. There are multiple captures in the file. I just need the text between Message-ID: and Received:

Comment: You may try `(?s)(?<=Message-ID:)(.*?)(?=Received:)|.` and replace with `(?{1}$1\n:)`. It should work for smaller files. That will also remove `Message-ID:` and `Received:`, BTW.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. This is also deleting the text between Message-ID and Received. I want to retain the text between these two

Comment: It is interesting: it does not work with lookarounds. Try `(?s)Message-ID:(.*?)Received:|.`, replace with `(?1$1\n)`. It works in my NPP.

Comment: If it works the way you need, let me know.

Comment: Yes. It works!! Thank you,Wiktor

Comment: @Prasad Glad to help. Please consider [accepting/upvoting my answer then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009103/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be straightforward if you only had a single occurrence of this text, and you only needed to extract the text inside the markers once.  In this case, something like the following would work:

```
Message-ID:(.*?)Received:
```

But if you expect to have multiple matches in your file, then you need to do more work.  Here is one pattern which should work:

```
(?:(?!Message-ID:).)*Message-ID:((?:(?!Received:)(?!Message-ID:).)*)Received:
```

Do a find on this pattern, and then replace with `$1`.  Note that dot must be in newline mode, meaning that `.*` matches across newlines (this mode is enabled in the demo).

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim.. I am getting an error “Can’t find the text”. Btw, I am using notepad++

Comment: @Prasad You need to do the replacement in regex mode, with dot set to match across newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?s)Message-ID:(.*?)Received:|.
```

Replace with `(?1$1\n)`.

**Details**

- `(?s)` - turn on `.` matches newline option
- `Message-ID:` - a literal substring
- `(.*?)`  -  Group 1: any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `Received:` - a literal substring
- `|` - or
- `.` - any 1 char.

The `(?1$1\n)` replacement means that if Group 1 matches, replace with Group 1 and append a newline after it, else, just remove the match.

[image]

Comment: This [may not work as intended](https://regex101.com/r/83vnc8/3) should the message and received markers ever appear in any other context.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are complicating the input while there is no need to since there are no such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`What does keep mean relative to the entire sample ? – sln yesterday`

Sometimes it pays to answer questions.

Find  `(?s)\G(?:.*?Message-ID:(.*?)Received:|.*)`
Replace `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/E3c3Ot/1